# I'm needing help configuring dual Radeon graphics cards to increase fps

Tags: amd-graphics, framerate

I am hoping to find someone or some people to help me configure setting for dual Radeon 7000 series graphics cards for optimal fps during gameplay. I have installed the second card and notice no difference in gameplay and sometimes from into the 40s range in fps only playing Terraria . I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with two Sapphire Radeon HD7870, AMD FX 8750 processor with 2x 8 GB Kingston ram 1333 MHz DDR 3.

Comment: It is a couple of years old, but you might want to read https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-CrossFire-mGPU

Comment: Thank you I will read that and post something afterward

Comment: Thank you Terrence that was interesting to find out.It sounds as if another video card will not improve anything on Linux. I hope I'm wrong and look forward to some information staying otherwise